# MAC Access Token Authentication IETF draft for OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, http-authentication, access-token, rfc

Does anybody know what happened to the IETF draft regarding the standardization of the HTTP MAC access authentication scheme for OAuth 2.0 ([draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac-00](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac-00))?

This internet draft expired on 12 November 2011 and the IETF tracker tool doesn't tell whether this proposal has been dropped or there has been a follow-up.

I would be interested to know the most up-to-date status of this draft since I should implement MAC access token authentication for an OAuth 2.0 web service I have been working on.

[Eran Hammer-Lahav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807187/eran-hammer-lahav), you there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured that out myself asking Eran Hammer-Lahav directly on [his blog](http://hueniverse.com/2011/12/sled-yahoo-and-moving-on/).

A new draft is expected as soon as the IETF Working Group can figure out how to proceed.

The current status of the MAC Access Authentication draft is on Eran's [github account](https://github.com/hueniverse/draft-hammer-http-mac).

Comment: Both your links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [new draft 04](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac-04) that expires 2014-01-16.